How can I add an empty Attribute column to an existing (ESRI) shapefile (.shp) [ or a Table] and populate it with values from a Raster (Image) layer?
I have a GIS layer of Agricultural Field Boundaries (cadastral boundaries) with dozen attributes including Owner's Name, Seasonwise Crop list, etc. I want to add and store a new attribute called Median-NDVI from a computed NDVI Raster layer by further computing median NDVI for each of the shapes (polygons representing the fields).
Using ArcGIS and ERDAS Imagine, we have been doing this operationally for years (part of well defined procedure).
Now I want to shift to GEE platform and use Cloud Storage and processing power.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site,  not a tutorial one. Questions here are expected to state what your research has indicated is the solution, what you have tried, and where you are stuck. For a coding problems, as in GEE, the relevant code block and the error or other problematic result is expected. Please [Exit] the Question to state what you have tried and where you are stuck.

You might want to check out the sampleRegions function.

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_regions
